# Application uploader error for In App Purchase content iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have a pack of 10 images that I want uploaded to Apples server for IAP. Uploading with Xcode crashes. Uploading with Application loader gives me different errors with the most common being:

"The file IOS_20Simulator_20Screen_20shot_2027_20feb_202014_2023.55.07.png is from the list of files requested by Apple, but it was not found locally." sometimes it says the same but with "image.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually after about 150 tries I managed to make it work. I had to have the same image added to the Appliction uploader "Screenshot for review" that I uploaded to Itunes connect when adding the IAP.