# itunesconnect iTMSTransporter hell - in app purchase bulk upload stopped working

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, xcode9, application-loader

This awesome feature called bulk upload of In app purchase items via csv -
 available via Application Loader so far, has been suddenly taken away by Apple from XCode 9 and on. I tried some previous versions of Application loaders (2.9.1) but they lacked this feature as well.

Today I had about 50 IAP items and I struggled with command line iTMSTransporter but got no way of working around it any way.

After entering some test IAP products on itunesconnect, I got itms (XML) file but could not upload it back to itunesconnect post adding my other IAP items.

- If I skip providing IAP screenshot, it complains about missing screenshot.
- If I provide existing valid file name present in the same folder as iTMSTransporter, it comes back with error:

  1.png is from the list of files requested by Apple, but it was not found locally.

I have already [tried naming it same on portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332511/application-uploader-error-for-in-app-purchase-content-ios) and my local storage but to no avail.

Why can't Apple make life simple enough for devs paying 30% of their hard earned money?

Comment: Application Loader used to work like a charm, and over the years it's become messier and messier to the point where it's just completely stopped working (And apple had to remove the In-App purchase upload altogether). I find this unacceptable from Apple, considering there are developers out there that are relying on their infrastructure to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing to do here was:

- **Not to put** screenshot files under the same folder as itms xml
- but to put it **inside itms** (as itms is a package, like zip file).

Having specified the same screenshot file name (inside metadata xml under review_screenshot section) as the one manually uploaded in itunesconnect for a test IAP item, following command worked like a charm:

```
iTMSTransporter -m upload -u "myuserid@myemail.com" -p "mypassword" -vendor_id "<itunes connect product id>" -f <path to itms package that contains metadata xml AND screenshot file>
```

Comment: Have you been able to upload hosted content using iTMSTransporter? I've been struggling with this command and I'm hoping maybe you could assist me with my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826675/cannot-upload-hosted-content-for-in-app-purchases-to-itunesconnect